# Is it possible to take the FB share dialog and after a user has shared, to then post a message to the users?

Tags: javascript, facebook, share

For example, the dialog below will open a new window to share from. After the window is closed out because the user has shared the post. Could you then do a overlay message from the original url using javascript?

http://www.upworthy.com/if-you-live-in-one-of-these-states-the-impact-of-washingtons-shenanigans-is-huge

The site above does something like this, just not sure how. If you click on share to facebook and then "x" out of the box, you'll see a overlay that happens after a user has either shared or closed the window. Is this done with javascript, if so how?

```
<a class="shareonfb" style="color: #fff;text-indent: 0px;padding-left: 35px;width: 130px;padding-top: 10px;height: 24px;" onClick="window.open (this.href, 'child', 'height=400,width=665,scrollbars'); return false" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://foo.com" target="_blank">Share on Facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a html file "parent.html" and put the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function open_win()
            {
                myWindow=window.open('popup.html','','width=300,height=250');
                myWindow.focus();
                myWindow.onbeforeunload = WindowCloseHanlder;
            }
            function WindowCloseHanlder(){
                myWindow.close();
                window.alert('Popup is closed');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to my Home Page</h1>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="open_win()">Share on Facebook</a>
</body>
</html>
```

create "popup.html" and put this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     <h1>I am pop up</h1>
     <p>Close this window</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You will see the javascript call after you close the popup window. Instead of alert message you can call your popup.

Comment: Ok, that makes since. How could I make a user opt out. Placing some sort of cookie or something?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you meant by user output?

Comment: no worries. Just articulated that wrong :)... What I mean, is there a way to have a button below how the example site does it and a user can click on the button to "not show this message anymore". Would that be done with cookies and javascript? I'm new and learning all this, but thank you for your help!